# condition on Posixct date

Tags: r, date, lubridate, radix

I have a heterogeneous data like
date are in POISXct format

```
ID birth new_birth 
1 1990-10-16 NA
2 1883-12-31 23:50:39 1983-12-31
3 1945-01-16 00:00:00 NA
```

I want to replace birth if there are something in new_birth and birth<1910
I change birth  & new_birth in Date time with as.Date
I want to create and new columns Year with

```
df <- df %>% 
 mutate(Year = as.date(birth, format="Y")
```

but Year stay at format YMD, why ?
and after I want to do  ifelse  to have finally

```
ID birth new_birth 
1 1990-10-16 NA
2 1983-12-31 1983-12-31
3 1945-01-16 NA
```

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_date_time` to change date and time in different formats to `POSIXct` class. If birth year is less than 1910 then replace `birth` value with `new_birth`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(birth = as.Date(parse_date_time(birth, c('Ymd', 'YmdHMS'))), 
         new_birth = as.Date(new_birth),
         birth = if_else(year(birth) < 1910, new_birth, birth))

#  ID      birth  new_birth
#1  1 1990-10-16       <NA>
#2  2 1983-12-31 1983-12-31
#3  3 1945-01-16       <NA>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, birth = c("1990-10-16", "1883-12-31 23:50:39", 
"1945-01-16 00:00:00"), new_birth = c(NA, "1983-12-31", NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you. It's  exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in a simpler way with `coalesce` - convert the different date time formats in both 'birth' columns with [`anydate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anytime/versions/0.3.9/topics/anytime) and [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/coalesce) the columns together

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
df %>%
    mutate(across(-ID, anydate), birth = coalesce(new_birth, birth))
  ID      birth  new_birth
1  1 1990-10-16       <NA>
2  2 1983-12-31 1983-12-31
3  3 1945-01-16       <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, birth = c("1990-10-16", "1883-12-31 23:50:39", 
"1945-01-16 00:00:00"), new_birth = c(NA, "1983-12-31", NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```